# random walk in netlogo- stoping condition issue

Tags: netlogo

I have created a small network consist of nodes which are connected through links. 
Some of the nodes are sources and some of the targets. I try to implement Random Walk algorithm.

I place walkers on source nodes, and walkers are moving randomly through the network. Now, I want to check walker reached to targets nodes, if all target nodes are visited by walker then ask walker to stop or die. 
I'm new to NetLogo and don't know how to implement this logic. 
Any help or guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have your nodes know if they are a target, and if they have been visited. That way, if a turtle visits a node, that node can be marked as having been visited. Then, you can have a `stop` procedure at the end of your go procedure that checks if any nodes are still present that are a target but have *not* been visited. I have made slight modifications to the Link-Walking Turtles Example to show one way that you could do this- almost all the code below is directly pulled from that model.

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [location]  
nodes-own [ target? visited? ] 

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  create-nodes 30 [ 
    set color blue 
    set target? false
    set visited? false
  ]
  ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]
  repeat 500 [ layout ]
  ask nodes [ 
    setxy 0.95 * xcor 0.95 * ycor 
  ]
  ask n-of 5 nodes [
    set target? true
    set color white
  ]

  create-walkers 1 [
    set color red
    set location one-of nodes
    move-to location
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to layout
  layout-spring nodes links 0.5 2 1
end

to go
  ask links [ set thickness 0 ]
  ask walkers [
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of location
    move-to new-location
    set location new-location
    ;; This gets turtles to ask their current location 
    ;; to set visited and target to true.
    ask location [
      set visited? true
      if target? = true [
        set color red
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ;; Check for target nodes that have NOT been visited. 
  ;; If there aren't any, stop the model.
  if not any? nodes with [ target? = true and visited? = false ] [
   print ("All target nodes have been visited.")
   stop
  ] 
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank so much for your kind help.

Comment: when I run this code, there is one issue. At the start, when any walker moves to new location, it set visited true and they stop. but I want that when all target nodes become visited then walker should stop.

Comment: Strange- you copied the code in exactly? I just created a blank file and pasted in the code above, created a `start` button and a `go` forever button on the interface, and [it worked](http://imgur.com/a/86q6U). Are you using Netlogo 6.0? Did you change your "View Updates" to "On Ticks" in the interface? If it is set to continuous, the model will run more or less instantaneously. M

Comment: oh. I did one stupid mistake, I did not set state variable in node creation.  now it works. thanks.

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted it out!

Comment: Hi, using the above-mentioned network, I calculated centrality measure ( closeness and betweenness). my question is can we implement random walk based on centrality measure. I mean walker should move from the most central node towards outside.

Comment: Hi sir, by using the above scenario and code. I want to add memory (list) with the walker. So that they save each location which is visited. the walker then looks at the list and should consider only those nodes which have not visited. how to do this, can you please guide me. @Luke C

Comment: Hi Waseem. Sorry, I missed your earlier comment. Both questions might be too complicated for a comment, so you may be better off asking a new question. For memory, if you want to try on your own first, you can make a `turtles-own` variable for the memory. Have the walkers add any nodes that it visits to that variable. Then you can use the `member?` primitive to check whether the node to which the walker wants to move is a member of that agentset or list. If you need more information than that, it is definitely better to ask a new question (you will get more visibility as well).